# Guidance needed for native customization Android apps

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, react-native

What I want to do is to create an app in react native which runs in the background 
as a service now whenever a person is navigating through any other application for example let it be the Android gallery than if he clicks any photo for more than 5  seconds in his gallery than the location of this photo must be sent to my app running in the background.
How do I achieve this via react native.

Comment: I think that you can try reading this post: https://hackernoon.com/easy-os-background-tasks-in-react-native-bc4476c48b8a

But.. I think that you will have to code with Java and not react-native

Comment: Well if I try to achieve this with Java than what I need to do